# Matching Entities - Self many to many

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working with a new master data management product, specifically people matching. 
I have two tables: Person and PersonMatch. PersonMatch is a join table that matches rows from Person to another row in Person.

Person: 1,2,3,4 (Per the PersonMatch, these are all the same Person).

PersonMatch: 1+2, 2+3, 3+4, 4+1

I can't wrap my head around a query to treat all four entities from the Person table as the same. Thanks for any help!

Comment: They cannot be...or we are missing info. If Person is not a dimension table, how does PersonMatch relate at all to Person? Ask again what does Person do and what does PersonMatch accomplish.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the structure of our data, and perhaps the purpose

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need a specific column that is a PersonUniqueId, and all the Person instances that are the same could have there own unique id to identify their differences, but they would each share the same 'PersonUniqueId', which reflects that they are really the same person, just with different or additional subsequent info.

If you do not go with a PersonUniqueId then you would need to figure out what in each record identifies the two persons as being the same, perhaps the name, or whatever else. Without knowing more about your overall structure It is hard to say what is the best direction, but hopefully this is a start.

It might be that the PersonMatch table is not even needed. Alternately, you could put the PersonUniqueId column in that table and then do something like:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Persons p, PersonMatch pm
WHERE p.PersonId = pm.PersonId
GROUP BY pm.PersonUniqueId
```

Hope this helps.